# Is there a way to query VoiceOver rotor mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tvos, voiceover

When VoiceOver is enabled on tvOS or iOS, is there an API to query which navigation mode is currently selected?  (i.e.: containers, headings, landmarks, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... is there an API to query which navigation mode is currently selected?

Under **iOS 13**, it's **currently not possible**.

Even if you can [add a new rotor option](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#custom-rotor) thanks to the `UIAccessibilityCustomRotor` since iOS 10, there's definitely no way to get the selected mode information from the rotor.